# Remove everything after last numeric value

Tags: php

I am trying to come up with a function that removes everything after the last numeric value of a string in PHP.

1. String example 1:

   ```
   input: "test test 12C"
   output: "test test 12"
   ```
2. String example 2:

   ```
   input: "test dddd 3323fff new 83dds"
   output: "test dddd 3323fff new 83"
   ```

How can I do this PHP?

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work and I'm not that good with `regex`:

```
$address = preg_replace('/[0-9]+$/', '', $row['address']);
```

Comment: whats your try on this?

Comment: **"How can I do this PHP?"** yes, how can you do it? you tell us your thoughts and some code trials and surely we would be able to help

Comment: added what ive been using so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with regular rexpressions:

```
.*[0-9]
```

**.*** matches any character (including none)

**[0-9]** matches any numberic character

So you're telling regex to match a string that starts with any characters followed by a numeric character.

```
<?php                                                                       
  $str = 'test dddd 3323fff new 83dds';
  preg_match('/.*[0-9]/', $str, $result);
  print_r($result[0]);
?>
```

Comment: your example leaves "dddd 3323fff new 83" which isnt really what i wanted since "test " dissapears

Comment: You should use `preg_match('/.*[0-9]/', $str, $result);` Then you have only 1 matched item and can use $result[0]

Comment: @TeeDeJee Doh! Yeah of course, thanks!
Chris: It works, you may copied it with a whitespace inside the regex?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite nicely with a regular expression. Only with a minor adjustment to the wording of the question, namely that you want to "save everything up to and including" the last numeric value.
In that case, the RegEx becomes:

```
$regexp = "/^(.*\\d)\\D∕";
```

This binds the RegEx to the start (`^`), then matches everything (`.*`), up to the last digit (`\d`) which is followed by a non-digit (`\D`). The parantheses around a part of the pattern tells the RegEx engine that you want to save everything in between them. This is called a "capturing sub group".

Check out the PHP manual for `preg_match()` for more information on how to utilize that regular expression.